# llvm error: Relocation not implemented yet! when running RxCpp in orcjit or lli

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, rxcpp, lli

I would like to run RxCpp example in llvm's IR interpreter `lli`.

Unfortunately, running any of the RxCpp examples fails in lli:

```
git clone https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxCpp.git --depth 1
cd RxCpp/Rx/v2/examples/pythogerian
clang++ -S -emit-llvm -fno-use-cxa-exit -I../../src main.cpp 
lli main.ll
```

error-message:

```
Relocation type not implemented yet!
UNREACHABLE executed at llvm/lib/ExecutionEngine/RuntimeDyld/RuntimeDyldELF.cpp:232!
```

Questions:

What does this error exactly mean ? - what assumptions are made within llvm's orc-jit that are not satisfied ?

Is there a workaround ? - are there any LLVM-IR transformations i can apply to make this work(e.g. through a compiler-flag) ?

What special features is RxCpp using that cause this problem in llvm's orcjit ?

tested on:

```
clang version 5.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang.git 6c9e299494de2a5b0425e46bc937f29a05128252) 
clang version 4.0.0-+rc1-1 (tags/RELEASE_400/rc1)
clang version 3.9.0-1 (tags/RELEASE_390/final)
clang version 3.8.1-12 (tags/RELEASE_381/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

Comment: you may want to mention which clang version you are using, and which platform you're on.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with `thread_local` / `__thread`.

Replacing `#define RXCPP_THREAD_LOCAL __thread` in `rx-utils.hpp` with whitespace "fixes" this issue.

The reason is a failure in the LLVM backend as it does not support TLS yet. This is related to [Bug 21431](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=21431) and the fact that some relocation strategies are missing in llvm's RuntimeDyld.